# How to add an "Extract archive" button to Windows 10 File Explorer toolbar

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Is there a way to add a toolbar button in Windows 10 File Explorer for an application-specific "Extract" archive action that can handle more than ".zip" files ? preferably via 7Zip but Winrar or even other applications are fine too. I mean the toolbar with big icons for the File,Share,View and so on panels / ribbon which holds actions like Cut, Delete, New folder or otherwise to the quick access toolbar.

Options like "Extract all", "Extract to..." are also accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 already has this. If you highlight a .Zip file, you'll see a 'Compressed Folder Tools' tab on the ribbon bar which has an 'Extract all' option on the right.

[image]

Comment: Yes but this is limited to .zip files only

Comment: Ok, but my answer met your requirements before you edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Most compression utilities add context menu entries that can do all you ask.
Adding buttons to the Ribbon of Explorer is much harder (if at all possible).

I suggest using such a product and going instead via the context menu of Explorer.
[Bandizip free](https://www.bandisoft.com/bandizip/)
can add many commands to the context menu, and one can customize which ones to chose.